# Trigger no funciona "ERROR: límite de profundidad de stack alcanzado"

Tags: trigger, pgadmin

Estoy usando **pgAdmin III**. La idea es que cuando se inserte un grupo, se compruebe si `tipo_targeta`, ya está en la tabla `grupo`, si está, se procede a insertar una nueva tubla, sino, lanzo un error.

**Funcion_Trigger:**

```
begin
  if(new.tipo_tarjeta in (Select distinct (tipo_tarjeta) from grupo))then
    insert into grupo values(new.grupo_id,new.cant_est,new.num_tarjeta,new.tipo_tarjeta,new.moneda_aceptada);
    return new;
  else
    raise exception 'La tarjeta no es del tipo correcto'; 
  end if; 
end;
```

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER verificar_targeta_en_grupo_nuevo
BEFORE INSERT
ON grupo
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "Funcion_Trigger"();
```

Y este es el error que me lanza:

> ```
> ERROR:  límite de profundidad de stack alcanzado
> HINT:  Incremente el parámetro de configuración «max_stack_depth»
> (actualmente 2048kB), después de asegurarse que el límite de
> profundidad de stack de la plataforma es adecuado.
> CONTEXT:  sentencia SQL: «SELECT (new.tipo_tarjeta in (Select distinct (tipo_tarjeta) from grupo))»
> función PL/pgSQL "funcion_trigger_añadir_grupo"() en la línea 3 en IF
> sentencia SQL: «insert into grupo values(new.grupo_id,new.cant_est,new.num_tarjeta,new.tipo_tarjeta,new.moneda_aceptada)»
> función PL/pgSQL "funcion_trigger_añadir_grupo"() en la línea 4 en sentencia SQL
> ```

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser una llamada recursiva: cada inserción en la tabla grupo lanza el trigger, que inserta de nuevo en grupo, lanzando de nuevo el trigger hasta el infinito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando insertar el mismo registro que provoca la ejecución del trigger. No necesitas hacer eso, simplemente haciendo el `RETURN NEW` provocarías la inserción del registro.

```
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.tipo_tarjeta IN (SELECT DISTINCT tipo_tarjeta FROM grupo)) THEN
    RETURN NEW;
  ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'La tarjeta no es del tipo correcto'; 
  END IF; 
END;
```

**NOTA**

Veo varios problemas a tu planteamiento. Para que la inserción se produzca tiene que haber al menos un registro que tenga el `tipo_tarjeta` que insertas, que se ha tenido que insertar antes de que el trigger exista y esté habilitado.

Puedes deshabilitar el trigger (`DISABLE TRIGGER`) para hacer la primera inserción y habilitarlo (`ENABLE TRIGGER`) para las siguientes (Lo cual no te recomiento). Quizás la solución más óptima pase por plantear tu problema de otra forma, como tener una tabla que almacene todos los `tipo_tarjeta` posibles.

Answer (score 1):

Me da la sensación de que tienes un trigger que se auto-ejecuta: una inserción provoca una inserción que provoca una inserción...

Prueba con esto:

```
CREATE TRIGGER verificar_tarjeta_en_grupo_nuevo
BEFORE INSERT
ON grupo
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0) --evitando la recursividad
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "Funcion_Trigger"();
```

Comment: Gracias, por ayudar, pero ahora dice "ERROR:  llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «grupo_id_pkey»
DETAIL:  Ya existe la llave (grupo_id)=(2501)." Y eso no es cierto, ya que el campo:grupo_id es integer incrementado de 1 en 1, y al incertar la nueva tupla, le estoy poniendo de id:2501, y el último id que tengo es 2500, incluso probre con 2600, y nada..lo mismo..

Comment: @Andry_UCI el error de recursividad es claro. Además, la función está usando el new.id, así que, así le pongas ID 9328749283784, vas a intentar insertarlo DOS VECES al menos.